# shared value is not coming correctly in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on the shared variable in crystal report and in that when I am sharing the value from subreport to main report the shared value is not correct.
Like in the subreport it's showing correct value but in the main report first value suppose to be 3.00 but it's coming as 0.00 and next value is coming what was the first value is which is 3.00 and 2nd value is going to 3rd position....

Comment: Where did you place the sub report and where are you showing in main report

Comment: I am placing the value in the group 2 of the subreport and doing the same in the main report. I change the place too but it's the same.

Comment: are you placing the variable on the main report in a different section than the subreport?